# Cambios de colores cuando es correcto o no la respuesta

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy realizando un ejercicio de realizar un quizz, que cuando se le de click al boton se haga la evaluación de que si la respuesta es correcta o no, y si lo es la respuesta se pondrá en verde. Y si no la respuesta seleccionada se pondrá en rojo.

```
<section id="pregunta0">
            <h3>1.- ¿De qué raza es Goku?</h3>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="1" name="pregunta0"onclick="respuesta(0,this)">Terricola
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="2" name="pregunta0" onclick="respuesta(0,this)">Saiyan
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="3" name="pregunta0" onclick="respuesta(0,this)">Tsufruianos
            </label>
        </section>

<button onclick="resultados()">Resultados</button>
        <h2>Cantidad de aciertos: <i class="resultado" id="resultado"></i></h2>
```

Tratando de encontrar una solución le añadí un id al label que contiene la respuesta para identificarla de los demás incisos, siendo el procedimiento que utilice el siguiente:

```
let correctas=[2];
let opcion_elegida=[];
let cantidad_correctas=0;

function respuesta(num_pregunta,seleccionada){
    //guardar respuesta elegida
    opcion_elegida[num_pregunta]=seleccionada.value;
    //el siguiente codigo es para poner en color blanco
    //el fondo de los inputs para cuando se elige otra opción
    //armo el id para seleccionar el section correspontiente
    id="pregunta" + num_pregunta;

    labels=document.getElementById(id).childNodes;
    labels[3].style.backgroundColor="white";
    labels[5].style.backgroundColor="white";
    labels[7].style.backgroundColor="white";

    seleccionada.parentNode.style.backgroundColor= "#cec0fc";
}


function resultados(){
 cantidad_correctas=0;
 for(i=0;i<correctas.length;i++){
        if(opcion_elegida[i]==null){
            alert("Responde todas las preguntas de opción multiple");
        }
        else{
            id="correcto"+i;
            if(correctas[i]==opcion_elegida[i]){       
                cantidad_correctas++;
                document.getElementById(id).style.background="#c0ff33";
            }
        }
    }
 document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML=cantidad_correctas;
}
```

Siendo esta una solución para poner en color verde la respuesta correcta, pero para las que son incorrectas aun no se como implementarlo.

Comment: tu código me está tronando, creo que en tu función resultados debes usar id="pregunta"+i en lugar de "correcto"+i

Comment: Se debe pintar verde al instante de presionar una opción o luego de presionar el botón Resultados???

Answer (score 2):

He empezado intentando arreglar tu código, pero me ha sido imposible, y he terminado refactorizándolo de este modo (las explicaciones están en el código):

```js
// almacenamos las respuestas correctas en un arrray
let respuestas_correctas = [2, 3];

// inicializamos un objeto que contendrá las opciones elegidas de cada pregunta
let opcion_elegida = {};

function respuesta(seleccionada) {

  // buscamos el objeto DOM de la sección que contiene la respuesta
  pregunta = seleccionada.closest('section')

  // buscamos todas suetiquetas label
  labels = pregunta.querySelectorAll('label');

  // las pintamos de blanco
  labels.forEach(el => el.style.backgroundColor = "white")

  // asignamos una clave/valor dentro del objeto opcion_elegida
  opcion_elegida[pregunta.id] = seleccionada.value

  // pintamos la opción seleccionada de gris
  seleccionada.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
}

function resultados() {

  // inicializamos esta variable que sumará las respuestas correctas
  let cantidad_correctas = 0;

  // inicializamos esta variable para detectar si falta responder alguna pregunta
  let preguntas_sin_responder = 0

  // verificamos si todas las preguntas tienen respuesta
  for (i = 0; i < respuestas_correctas.length; i++) {

    // comprobamos si la pregunta tiene alguna respuesta marcada
    if (opcion_elegida['pregunta' + i] == null) {

      // si no tiene respuesta asignamos un valor distinto de 0 
      preguntas_sin_responder = 1

      // mostramos la alerta
      alert("Responde todas las preguntas de opción multiple");

      // salimos del bucle para no repetir la alerta
      break;
    }
  }

  // si todas tienen respuesta entonces
  if (preguntas_sin_responder == 0) {

    // nos recorremos sus resultados
    for (i = 0; i < respuestas_correctas.length; i++) {

      // encontramos la sección
      id = document.getElementById("pregunta" + i)

      // buscamos todos sus label
      labels = id.querySelectorAll('label');

      // los ponemos en blanco
      labels.forEach(el => el.style.backgroundColor = "white")

      // buscamos los inputs en esta sección
      inputs = id.querySelectorAll("input")

      // nos recorremos todos los inputs 
      inputs.forEach(el => {

        // comprobamos si estan marcados y son correctos
        if (el.value == respuestas_correctas[i] &&
          opcion_elegida['pregunta' + i] == el.value) {

          // agregamos 1 al total de respuestas correctas
          cantidad_correctas++;

          // lo pintamos de azul
          el.parentNode.style.background = "blue";
        } else {

          // si no es correcto pero esta marcado 
          if (opcion_elegida['pregunta' + i] == el.value) {

            // lo pintamos de rojo
            el.parentNode.style.background = "red";
          }
        }
      })
    };

    // imprimimos el resultado del test
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = cantidad_correctas;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="pregunta0">
  <h3>1.- ¿De qué raza es Goku?</h3>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="pregunta0" value="1" onclick="respuesta(this)">Terricola
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="pregunta0" value="2" onclick="respuesta(this)">Saiyan
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="pregunta0" value="3" onclick="respuesta(this)">Tsufruianos
  </label>
</section>

<section id="pregunta1">
  <h3>1.- ¿Cuanto son dos más dos?</h3>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="pregunta1" value="1" onclick="respuesta(this)">6
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="pregunta1" value="2" onclick="respuesta(this)">1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="pregunta1" value="3" onclick="respuesta(this)">4
  </label>
</section>

<button onclick="resultados()">Resultados</button>
<h2>Cantidad de aciertos: <i class="resultado" id="resultado"></i></h2>
```

Por favor, pregúntame lo que no entiendas en los comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Te ofrezco una alternativa basada en css, que a mí me parece más simple.

Lo primero es crear un atributo al que le llamé "data-correct", donde guardas true para la respuesta correcta o false para la incorrecta (en este último caso también es válido no colocar este atributo)

Luego unos labels emparejados con los radio

```
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="pregunta0" data-correct="false" id="p_0_1" />
    <label for="p_0_1">Terricola</label>

    <input type="radio" value="1" name="pregunta0" data-correct="true" id="p_0_2" />
    <label for="p_0_2">Saiyan</label>

    <input type="radio" value="1" name="pregunta0" data-correct="false" id="p_0_3" />
    <label for="p_0_3">Tsufruianos</label>
```

Para marcar color verde o rojo la respuesta correcta solo se necesita este css

```
input:checked + label {
    background-color: red;
    color:white;
}

input:checked[data-correct="true"] + label {
    background-color: forestgreen;
}
```

Para obtener la cantidad de preguntas correctas solo se necesita una línea de código

```
document.querySelectorAll('input:checked[data-correct="true"]').length
```

Dejo una demo:

```js
const ResultadoElement = document.getElementById("resultado")

function resultados(){
   ResultadoElement.innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked[data-correct="true"]').length;
}
```

```css
section{
 margin: 20px 0;
}
label {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 140px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition-property: color, background-color;
    transition-duration: 0.6s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

input[type="radio"]{
    visibility:collapse;
}
input:checked + label {
    background-color: red;
    color:white;
}

input:checked[data-correct="true"] + label {
    background-color: forestgreen;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<section id="pregunta0">
    <h3>1.- ¿De qué raza es Goku?</h3>

    <input type="radio" value="1" name="pregunta0" data-correct="false" id="p_0_1" />
    <label for="p_0_1">Terricola</label>

    <input type="radio" value="1" name="pregunta0" data-correct="true" id="p_0_2" />
    <label for="p_0_2">Saiyan</label>

    <input type="radio" value="1" name="pregunta0" data-correct="false" id="p_0_3" />
    <label for="p_0_3">Tsufruianos</label>
 
</section>

<button onclick="resultados()">Resultados</button>
<h2>Cantidad de aciertos: <i class="resultado" id="resultado"></i></h2>
```